# PyQtgraph - Plotting real-time data - Add "line labels" next to graph which move up and down in concert with real-time data (see illustration in post)

Tags: real-time, pyqtgraph, qtgui, real-time-data, event-based-programming

I'm plotting 2 lines on a pyqtgraph in real-time (simultaneously), and I'd like to add line labels on the right of the graph, that move up and down with the incoming real-time data, as if 'attached' to the end of the plotted line.

It's a bit difficult to explain in words, so I made an image to illustrate the desired result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/h3kgm.png

My question is: is this possible in PyQtGraph? If yes, does anyone have an example I could use as inspiration? If not, which libraries would allow me to achieve this result?

Comment: Can you share code that you've tried so far?

Comment: Unfortunately, I haven't been able to achieve this in pyqtgraph, and have moved on to another solution since then. So I don't have much left of my previous code for this.